# maven dependency on uber jar, local vs jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, dependencies, repository

I have project A that uses a certain 3rd party repository and dependent on a few jars from that repo.

I compile Project A with dependencies(a fat Jar) and upload it to my artifactory.
Now i start project B, but i dont want him to have that 3rd party repo, because all the classes i need are already in that fat jar i have in the artifactory.
So i only add a dependency for project A in project B ( project B has my artifactory as a repo)

When i build project B at my jenkins server, everything goes well, but when i try to compile project B on my local computer ( that has access to artifactory) i fail cause he tries to download some dependencies of project A while not having the 3rd party repository.

I am well aware that its not the best way to work, but what i dont get is why on my local environment i get the error while the jenkins doesnt?

I thought if the classes exists maven wont try to download the dependencies from an external repo, and the classes exists in my case, if i go into my local .m2 repo, and look at projects As jar, i can see the classes are present.

Why did jenkins succeed the build and i didnt?

Comment: Let me just mention that using a fat jar as dependency is usually a bad idea. More so, if the pom.xml of the fat jar still contains all the dependencies so that Maven will try to download them, effectively duplicating your loaded classes

Answer (score 1):

If you use the same Jenkins node to build your project B where you have built project A initially then Maven is using A's dependencies from local Maven repository. Try to clean it and then build project B there - does the job still succeed?

You may use following dependency declaration in project B to exclude ALL transitive dependencies of A:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>groupA</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactA</artifactId>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>
            <groupId>*</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclude>
    </excludes>
</dependency>
```